# Scala's @throws annotation is ignored in javac if I declare the variable as its abstract superclass

Tags: java, scala, exception, annotations, throws

In Java you can't specify that an overridden abstract method `throws` some exception if the original abstract method does not (`overridden method does not throw Exception`.) However in Scala you *can* do this since it doesn't have checked exceptions. Fine, but if you use the `@throws` annotation that should tip the Java compiler off to what's going on, right?

Given this Scala code:

```
package myscala

abstract class SFoo {
    def bar(): Unit
}

class SFoobar extends SFoo {
    @throws[Exception]
    override def bar(): Unit = {
        throw new Exception("hi there")
    }
}
```

I have two different Java programs, one of which will compile and run into an `Exception` at runtime, and the other which will not compile.

Compiles:

```
import myscala.SFoo;
import myscala.SFoobar;

public class Foobar {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SFoo mySFoo = new SFoobar();
        mySFoo.bar();
    }
}
```

Doesn't compile (`unreported exception Exception; must be caught or declared to be thrown`):

```
import myscala.SFoo;
import myscala.SFoobar;

public class Foobar {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SFoobar mySFoo = new SFoobar();       // only difference is the declared type
        mySFoo.bar();
    }
}
```

I don't really get it. Why doesn't the Java compiler pick up on the fact that I'm declaring that `SFoobar.bar` throws an exception even though `Foo.bar` has no such declaration, and as a result, raise a similar compilation error?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you convert the Scala code for `SFoo` and `SFooBar` to equivalent Java code:

```
abstract class SFoo {
    void bar() {}
}

class SFoobar extends SFoo {
    void bar() throws Exception {
        throw new Exception("hi there");
    }
}
```

It doesn't compile, because:

```
error: bar() in SFoobar cannot override bar() in SFoo
        void bar() throws Exception {
             ^
  overridden method does not throw Exception
```

Java enforces the rule that overriding methods cannot throw exceptions that weren't thrown by the method they are overriding. This makes checked exceptions typesafe when upcasting, e.g. when converting a `SFooBar` to an `SFoo`.

Your first definition of the  `FooBar` class, where an `SFooBar` is stored in a `SFoo` variable, would be perfectly safe if `SFoo` and `SFooBar` had been defined in Java. The Java compiler knows that an `SFoo.bar` doesn't throw `Exception`, assumes that the rule for overridden methods was observed, and so doesn't do any extra checks here.

However, the Scala compiler doesn't care about this rule for overridden methods, and will allow you to break this type safety. The Java compiler is oblivious to this fact, and so produces code that breaks at runtime. It's a mismatch between Java and Scala that neither compiler can work around.